# is it possible to define location as double[][]

Tags: twitter4j

I am using Twitter4j where I am using QueryFilter Class and it says

http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/FilterQuery.html#locations
private double[][] locations

I tried my every best but couldnt find my way out how to define location as double
or maybe I just don't know how to use this Location.

Please don't ban me because of this question.

I have already spent my whole day searching this thing and couldn't find an answer.

any help would be appreciated.

Bye,

Sara

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have found the answer as below,

Actually you will have to define  as bounding box SW and NE as below

double[][] bbox = {{51.282534682474655, 3.153076171875}, {53.8460456413833, 7.327880859375}};

First pair is SW while second is NE

Hopefully it will help.